# how can I Re-Direct a printer in windows os

Tags: c++, windows, hook, driver

I use the code from printmirror, now I hook enumprinter api to hide my printer. when peopel choose a real printer to print the doc I hook createdcw to my printer. I　really wanna know how I can do it.

Comment: How you can do what?  What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. Windows uses a print spooler for print jobs. The print spooler consists of several layers including *Print Provider*, *Print Processor*, *Port Monitor*, *Language Monitor* etc. All of these components can be customized, meaning you can write your own components and replace them in the print spooler. From within these components, you will be able to redirect print jobs. Each of these components give you different formats of the print data after the previous layer processes it.

This can get you started - http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/06/19/basic-printing-architecture.aspx